# Speed up a multiple video files in a one project

Tags: video

I have 7 video files, which I need to speed up to 10 times and render as 1 videofile. The problem is when I add effect->speed control to each file, there are huge gaps with last frame between splits.
**For example 1st video is 10 min. I set multiple to 10. In a render it played 1 min fast (as I expected) but the last 9 min is a one damn last frame.** 
**How to make proper speeded video with a few splits?** Maybe I need to manualy calculate acelerated length after which delete unwanted trash? 
Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try grouping all of the clips into a meta-strip with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> then apply the speed effect to that meta-strip.

Answer (score 0):

A speed ramp will only work if there is movement in the frame and the following conditions are met
1) Subject(s) are moving and camera is still.
2) Camera is moving and Subject(s) are still.
3) Both Camera and Subject(s) are moving.

However, if there is absolutely zero movement in the scene, the speeded up footage will obviously look like a single frame.

Please check the video for these motionless parts and remove them before you try speeding it up.

If you still need help, let me know. There are other tools better suited to time remapping a video by the way.